# Apache Beam/Dataflow- passing file path to ReadFromText

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a use case where I want to read the filename from a metadata table, I have written a pipeline function to read the metadata table, but I am not sure how can I pass this information to ReadFromText as it only takes string as input, Is it possible to assign this value to ReadFromText(). Please suggest some workarounds or ideas how to achieve this, Thanks

code: pipeline | 'Read from a File' >> ReadFromText(I want to pass the file path here?,
skip_header_lines=1)

Note: There will be various folders and files in storage, files are in csv format, but in my use case I can't directly pass the storage location or filename to file path in ReadFromText. I want to read it from metadata and pass the value. Hope I am clear, Thanks

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to and try to update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to read the metadata. If you want to read all the files inside a folder, you can just provide a blob. This solution working in python, not sure about java.

```
p|readfromtext("./folder/*.csv")
```

"*" is the blob here, which allows pipeline to read all the patterns matching .csv. You can also add something at the starting.

Comment: I cant use this because of use case, here we have to see the metadata to understand which folder to look into

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [`textio.ReadAllFromText`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.36.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadAllFromText) which reads from a PCollection instead of taking a string directly.

Comment: Thanks this will help in reading from pcollection, but is there any way i can iterate over a pcollection? Thanks